# issue in ios with compressing, base64 encoding, and form-posting json data

Tags: android, ios, xcode, base64, gzip

so we're on the same page: i'm using [NSData+GZIP](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Gzip), JSONKit, and [NSData+Base64](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html)

my goal here, as the title suggests, is to take a json object, compress it, base64 encode it, and send it up to a .net server as a form post which in turn expects to take this data and reverse the process and end with a json object.

i need to do this on both android and iOS. android is done, it works well. for reference, here is what i'm doing there:

```
public String compress(String string) throws IOException {
    byte[] blockcopy = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(string.length()).array();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(string.length());
    GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
    gos.write(string.getBytes());
    gos.close();
    os.close();
    byte[] compressed = new byte[4 + os.toByteArray().length];
    System.arraycopy(blockcopy, 0, compressed, 0, 4);
    System.arraycopy(os.toByteArray(), 0, compressed, 4, os.toByteArray().length);

    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0; i<compressed.length; i++)
        hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & compressed[i]));

    return Base64.encodeBytes(compressed);
}
```

here is a test on iOS that succeeds:

```
    NSLog(@"test? %@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[[NSData dataFromBase64String:[[[@"test" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] gzippedData] base64EncodedString]] gunzippedData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

this prints:

```
"test? test"
```

the area of concern:

```
    NSStringEncoding encoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;

    NSString* string = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableData] JSONString];
    NSData* data = [string dataUsingEncoding:encoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/myendpoint.aspx?deviceid=%@&accesstoken=%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"deviceId"], [defaults objectForKey:@"ggAccessToken"]]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSMutableData *requestBodyData = nil;

    requestBodyData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Create boundry
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSData *boundaryData = [[[@"--" stringByAppendingString:boundary] stringByAppendingString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:encoding];

    // Add Data to POST
    [requestBodyData appendData:boundaryData];
    [requestBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: multipart/form-data; "] dataUsingEncoding:encoding]];
    [requestBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=\"%@\"; ", @"contacts"] dataUsingEncoding:encoding]];

    [requestBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:encoding]];

    NSString* finalString = [[data gzipDeflate] base64EncodedString];
    //an example of finalString at this point: H4sIAAAAAAAAA6WOwQrCMAyGX0VyUqjHOtk7CN5HGekWMdB2knansXc3FcSDKIiHhBC+5P+6BWYJGdrOGbhdp0R1XiCgpwAtnCbPgcBAmqMn0c3WWrvbaNtrWVjNC+ZzffARPsCqIRSRn4EXllz6hJGULcK5YNJzHEehnB8qrgb8o9j8onj8rjigCNObobsD+2WV/kYBAAA=

    NSData* finalData = [finalString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [requestBodyData appendData:finalData];
    [requestBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:encoding]];
    [requestBodyData appendData:boundaryData];

    [request setHTTPBody:requestBodyData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [data objectFromJSONData]);
    }];
```

all seems well at this point, but the result from the (.net)server:

```
ERROR TYPE: System.IO.InvalidDataException - ERROR MESSAGE: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream. -
```

i realize there isn't much of a question here just yet, but heres something of one:
what could i be doing at this point that would yield incorrectly compressed data? (lets assume at this time at all is correct server-side given that android is fully functional and the guy who built that side of it is pretty damn experienced)...

Comment: In your test you zipped with `gzippedData`, but in your code sample you zipped with `gzipDeflate`. I don't know `NSData+GZip`, but do these two methods do the same thing?

Comment: sorry, i'm running a million different tests in an effort to figure this out... one of such tests is trying alternative libraries. thats what you're seeing there. same result, just an equivalent call from a different library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to use gzip, as a stream, or as a data file.  The compression itself doesn't require a header, but when saved to a file, it is standard to include the header and footer bytes as defined in the [RFC](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html).

So the problem is one library is looking for the header, while the other library that wrote the data didn't include it, it's probably just a raw stream of gzip data. It can be decompressed, but the library needs to know to not look for the headers.

When saving to a file, there are additional benefits of the file format, mainly due to the CRC check that is included at the end of the file to help verify that the data integrity of the file has not been corrupted.

Comment: in the interest of testing this theory, do you think it would be easier to not look for a header on the server side or figure out how to include one on the iOS side?

Comment: Depends which library is more flexible, I don't think NSData+GZIP as you have it will save the file with the header. I would think the .NET counterpart has the ability to decode a raw gzip stream

Comment: you get the sought after green checkmark for sending me down the right path. it turns out that in order to get the android side to work, we were chopping the first 4 bytes on the server side to get to the "magic number" in the header, where on iOS the "magic number" was at the start of the stream and was getting chopped... HOLY HELL i just put so many hours into this... your help is much appreciated my friend!

Comment: @MrTristan no problem, glad to be of help!